# ANTLR4: grun errors while using separate grammar (ClassCastException)

Tags: antlr4

### Description

I'm trying to create a custom language that I want to separate lexer rules from parser rules. Besides, I aim to divide lexer and parser rules into specific files further (e.g., common lexer rules, and keyword rules).

But I don't seem to be able to get it to work.

Although I'm not getting any errors while generating the parser (`.java` files),  `grun` fails with `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException`.

#### Note

I'm running ANTLR`4.7.2` on Windows7 targeting Java.

### Code

I created a set of files that closely mimic what I intend to achieve. The example below defines a language called `MyLang` and separates lexer and parser grammar. Also, I'm splitting lexer rules into four files:

1. ```
   // MyLang.g4
   parser grammar MyLang;

   options { tokenVocab = MyLangL; }

   prog
       : ( func )* END
       ;

   func
       : DIR ID L_BRKT  (stat)* R_BRKT
       ;

   stat
       : expr SEMICOLON
       | ID OP_ASSIGN expr SEMICOLON
       | SEMICOLON
       ;

   expr
       : expr OPERATOR expr
       | NUMBER
       | ID
       | L_PAREN expr R_PAREN
       ;
   ```
2. ```
   // MyLangL.g4
   lexer grammar MyLangL;

   import SkipWhitespaceL, CommonL, KeywordL;

   @header {
   package com.invensense.wiggler.lexer;
   }

   @lexer::members {   // place this class member only in lexer
   Map<String,Integer> keywords = new HashMap<String,Integer>() {{
       put("for",          MyLangL.KW_FOR);
       /* add more keywords here */
   }};
   }

   ID  :   [a-zA-Z]+
           {
           if ( keywords.containsKey(getText()) ) {
               setType(keywords.get(getText())); // reset token type
           }
           }
       ;

   DIR
       : 'in'
       | 'out'
       ;

   END : 'end' ;
   ```
3. ```
   // KeywordL.g4
   lexer grammar KeywordL;

   @lexer::header {    // place this header action only in lexer, not the parser
   import java.util.*;
   }

   // explicitly define keyword token types to avoid implicit def warnings
   tokens {
       KW_FOR
       /* add more keywords here */
   }
   ```
4. ```
   // CommonL.g4
   lexer grammar CommonL;

   NUMBER
       : FLOAT
       | INT
       | UINT
       ;

   FLOAT
       : NEG? DIGIT+ '.' DIGIT+ EXP?
       | INT
       ;

   INT
       : NEG? UINT+
       ;

   UINT
       : DIGIT+ EXP?
       ;

   OPERATOR
       : OP_ASSIGN
       | OP_ADD
       | OP_SUB
       ;

   OP_ASSIGN   : ':=';
   OP_ADD      : POS;
   OP_SUB      : NEG;

   L_BRKT          : '[' ;
   R_BRKT          : ']' ;
   L_PAREN         : '(' ;
   R_PAREN         : ')' ;
   SEMICOLON       : ';' ;

   fragment EXP
       : [Ee] SIGN? DIGIT+
       ;

   fragment SIGN
       : POS
       | NEG
       ;

   fragment POS: '+' ;
   fragment NEG : '-' ;
   fragment DIGIT : [0-9];
   ```
5. ```
   // SkipWhitespaceL.g4
   lexer grammar SkipWhitespaceL;

   WS
       :   [ \t\r\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN)
       ;
   ```

### Output

Here is the exact output I receive from the code above:

```
ussjc-dd9vkc2 | C:\M\w\s\a\l\example
§ antlr4.bat .\MyLangL.g4

ussjc-dd9vkc2 | C:\M\w\s\a\l\example
§ antlr4.bat .\MyLang.g4

ussjc-dd9vkc2 | C:\M\w\s\a\l\example
§ javac *.java

ussjc-dd9vkc2 | C:\M\w\s\a\l\example
§ grun MyLang prog -tree
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class MyLang
        at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Unknown Source)
        at org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig.process(TestRig.java:135)
        at org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig.main(TestRig.java:119)

ussjc-dd9vkc2 | C:\M\w\s\a\l\example
§
```

Answer (score 4):

Rename both of your file with MyLangParser and MyLangLexer, then run `grun MyLang prog -tree`